# Display post structure in function

Tags: posts, customization

I have custom post type : edge, so I built some content by Visual composer.
Now I need to display all post type edge in my page.

I use the following code in function to get posts but I can not keep the whole site structure by post_content.

```
   $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => 'edge');
   $edge_array = get_posts( $args );
   foreach($edge_array as $e):
    echo $e->post_content; 
   endforeach;
```

it display the whole content but not styling like

[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_column_text]
product
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/2"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_column_text]

I really want it to display exactly in the post with style, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the post content through the [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function before displaying it.

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => 'edge');
$edge_array = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($edge_array as $e):
    echo do_shortcode($e->post_content); 
endforeach;
```